# Puppeteer Chromium can't browse

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a node app to evaluate a web page. It was working fine until I changed the computer. After reinstalling, Puppeteer can't find any page, getting this message:

```
RESULT_CODE_NORMAL_EXIT_EXP3
```

```js
async function Prueba() {
const Apify = require('apify');
Apify.main(async () => {
    puppeteer=require('puppeteer')
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],  headless: false 
      });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.goto("https://www.smoreno.com.ar");
})
```

Comment: [tag:puppeteer] != [tag:puppet].  Tags edited.

Comment: Also, do you mean "*chromium*"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--no-sandbox` argument:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
    headless: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
});
```